# Создать цель по клику на маркер

Tags: google-maps-api, карты, google-tag-manager

Как можно в Google TagManager отследить нажатие по маркеру на карте?

Читал, что есть метод `onMarkerClick`, но не догоню никак, куда копать дальше.